# Why is include JSON::Serializable needed in this struct in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

In order to do .to_json on this Struct of Book, the `include JSON::Serializable` is needed, there are answers for this in other languages, but I thought there should be something about this in Crystal or Crystal lang.

```
struct Book
    include JSON::Serializable # Needed to parse JSON
    def initialize(
      @Id : Int32,
      @Title : String,
      @Author : String,
      @Desc : String
    )
    end
end
```

https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.4.1/JSON.html#generating-with-to-json Here is some documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JSON::Serializable` module automatically generates methods for JSON serialization when included.

Including `JSON::Serializable` will create `#to_json` and `self.from_json` methods on the current class, and a constructor which takes a `JSON::PullParser`. By default, these methods serialize into a *json* object containing the value of every instance variable, the keys being the instance variable name.

Comment: Thanks, added to answers, good for people when searching.